# would this be an example of deep copy?

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy

```
int[] a = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = randomFill();//randomFill is a method that generates random numbers
}

int[] b = new int[a.length];
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    b[j] = a[j]
}

int[] c = new int[a.length];
for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
    c[k] = a[k]
}
```

are both array b and array c the deep copy of array a?
I need to modify array a but want to keep its original values so that I can use it for later and the hint I received was to use deep copy. I can't tell if my code is considered as deep copy ...

Comment: That's a shallow copy, but since you're working with primitives and not objects, a shallow copy is all you need (there's no actual difference).

Comment: Yes, if it would compile, both b and c would be deep copies of a. Add a few semicolons to make it compile.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `b = c = a;`

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: That isn't even a copy. There's only one array with multiple references.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: yes, that too.

Comment: An assignment to another variable is a copy of the reference. That is as shallow as it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is an array of `int`(s), they only have a primitive value - so the answer is yes. Modifying `b` (or `c`) will not affect `a`. But, you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) like

```
int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Deep copy` term couldn't be applied to copying plain array of integers. This is about more complex data structures like collections of objects which can also contain nested objects/collections.

Comment: It is a deep copy too. A shallow copy would only copy the references: `b = a; c = a;`. You are right that deep copies usually also have to copy deeply nested contents, but there aren't any here.